# tableview is empty when i add an item

Tags: java, javafx

I need help with an empty tableview.
When I put items in an ObservableList and do setItems with this list, the tableview doesn't show the items from the list.

I have included Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example(I think).

Main class.

```
 public class GeneralController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Subvencio> tabla;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Subvencio, Double> ctotal;
     @FXML
    private TableColumn<Subvencio, String> cesport;
    ObservableList<Subvencio> subs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        cesport.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Subvencio, String>("Esport"));
        ctotal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Subvencio, Double>("Total"));
        tabla.setItems(subs);
    }

    //Mètode per a afegir una subvenció a la llista(Mitjansant un scene diferent i un showandWait).
    @FXML
    private void afegir(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        //Carregem el controlador i inicialitzem la finestra a obrir.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/model/Afegir.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage ventana2= new Stage();
        ventana2.setMinHeight(380);
        ventana2.getIcons().add(new Image("/estil/Boo.png"));
        ventana2.setMinWidth(770);
        ventana2.setTitle("Afegir dades");
        ventana2.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        ventana2.setScene(scene);
        //Fem que espere fins a ser tancada i coloquem els elements a la taula.subs = new ObservableList<Subvencio>();
        ventana2.showAndWait();
        tabla.setItems(subs);
}
```

Afegir Class.

```
   public class AfegirController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField esport;
    @FXML
    private TextField equips;
    @FXML
    private TextField despeses;
    @FXML
    private TextField esportistes;
    @FXML
    private TextField puntuacio;
    @FXML
    private TextField socis;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox festes;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox disiplina;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox voluntari;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox instalacions;
    @FXML
    private Button bafegir;
    Subvencio sub = new Subvencio();
    
    //Metode per a afegir una subvencio a la llista de elements.
    @FXML
    private void afegir(ActionEvent event) {
        //Comprobem si tots els textfielsd estan omplits, sino es així, mostrem un error.
         if ((!equips.getText().isEmpty())
            && (equips.getText().trim().length()!=0)
            && (!despeses.getText().isEmpty())
            && (despeses.getText().trim().length()!=0)
                && (!esportistes.getText().isEmpty())
            && (esportistes.getText().trim().length()!=0)
                && (!puntuacio.getText().isEmpty())
            && (puntuacio.getText().trim().length()!=0)
                && (!socis.getText().isEmpty())
            && (socis.getText().trim().length()!=0)
                && (!esport.getText().isEmpty())
            && (esport.getText().trim().length()!=0))
         { 
             //Passem els valors de el textfield als seus corresponents formats.
            int aux1 = Integer.parseInt(equips.getText());
            double aux2 = Double.parseDouble(despeses.getText());
            int aux3 = Integer.parseInt(esportistes.getText());
            int aux4 = Integer.parseInt(puntuacio.getText());
            int aux5 = Integer.parseInt(socis.getText());
            boolean aux6 = festes.isSelected();
            boolean aux7 = disiplina.isSelected();
            boolean aux8 = voluntari.isSelected();
            boolean aux9 = instalacions.isSelected();
            String aux10 = esport.getText();
           //Carregem un controllardor per poder crear subvencions i la creeem. en cabar aques proces la finestra es tanca.
           GeneralController aux = new GeneralController();
           sub.setEsport(aux10);
           sub.setEquips(aux1);
           sub.setEsportistes(aux3);
           sub.setFestes(aux6);
           sub.setFormacio(aux7);
           sub.setInstalacions(aux9);
           sub.setPuntuacio(aux4);
           sub.setSocis(aux5);
           sub.setVoluntari(aux8);
           sub.setdespeses(aux2);
           aux.subs.add(sub);
           Node minodo = (Node) event.getSource(); 
           minodo.getScene().getWindow().hide();
         }
         else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            //Apliquem el css cridant al metode dialogpane
            DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();
            dialogPane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/estil/flatterfx.css").toExternalForm());
            dialogPane.getStyleClass().add("button");
            Stage stage = (Stage) alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
            stage.getIcons().add(
                new Image(this.getClass().getResource("/estil/Boo.png").toString()));
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setHeaderText("Error al afegir una subvenció.");
            alert.setContentText("Deus emplenar tots els cuadres de text per poder afegir una subvenció.");
            Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
         
         }
    }
    public void inicializaSubvencio (Subvencio aux){
        sub = aux;
        String aux1 = String.valueOf(aux.getEsport());
        String aux2 = String.valueOf(aux.getEquips());
        String aux3 = String.valueOf(aux.getDespeses());
        String aux4 = String.valueOf(aux.getEsportistes());
        String aux5 = String.valueOf(aux.getEsportistes());
        String aux6 = String.valueOf(aux.getPuntuacio());
        String aux7 = String.valueOf(aux.getSocis());
        String aux8 = String.valueOf(aux.getTotal());
        double total = aux.getTotal();
        esport.setText(aux1);
        equips.setText(aux2);
        despeses.setText(aux3);
        esportistes.setText(aux5);
        puntuacio.setText(aux6);
        socis.setText(aux7);
        festes.setSelected(aux.getFestes());
        disiplina.setSelected(aux.getFormacio());
        voluntari.setSelected(aux.getVoluntari());
        instalacions.setSelected(aux.getInstalacions());
    }
}
```

And subvencio class.

```
public class Subvencio {
    String esport;
    int equips;
    double despeses;
    int esportistes;
    int puntuacio;
    int socis;
    boolean festes;
    boolean formacio;
    boolean voluntari;
    boolean instalacions;
    double total;
    
    //Mètodes generals de creacio d'una subvenció.
    public Subvencio() {
        this(null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false);
    }
    
    public Subvencio(String esport, double total, double despeses, int equips, int esportistes, int puntuacio, 
            int socis, boolean festes, boolean formacio, 
            boolean voluntari, boolean instalacions) {
        this.esport = esport;
        this.total = 0;
        this.despeses = despeses;
        this.equips = equips;
        this.esportistes = esportistes;
        this.puntuacio = puntuacio;
        this.socis = socis;
        this.festes = festes;
        this.formacio = formacio;
        this.instalacions = instalacions;
        this.voluntari = voluntari;
    }
    
    //Mètodes getters i setters per poder treballar amb els valors que contè una subvenció.
    public String getEsport() {
    return esport;
    }

    public void setEsport(String esport) {
    this.esport = esport;
    }
}
```

Edit: @James_D : I use an instance of one of your controllers because if i don't do this, netbeans say me "non-static variable subs can not be referenced from a static context" and my professor at university say me that this rapair that error. I have other example form a pc store and i use this fix and this erros isn't appear in the example but in this app it appears.

Mi idea for this app is like this:
When a push a button and  textfields are fill the program close that windows and put a subvencio in a tableview at the 2nd window.My problem is when i do that the tableview don't show any item on tableview.

Added a mega link with my app for check all of code and test the error.
[Subvencio App](https://mega.nz/#!9sV0VLII!aMQvOnmzp6REhZKWH-6hzt1_w5Cye9ZefAIUIgvElA0)

I added a link because i don't know if in my minimal code can test the error.
To reproduce the error you can open the app push afegir button and fill the textfields.After that, push afegir again.
Thanks for helpping me.

Comment: Could you show the `inicializaSubvencio` method and enough of `Subvencio` to see, how you implement the properties?

Comment: I don't see the definition of TableView and what the template class (if, you have) is you have created it with. I think you can show a bit more of code, to start with, the methods you have referenced in these snippets.

Comment: About not seeing data in the TableView. Assume, `data` is the ObservableList and `tabV` is the TableView. Try the following, `tabV.setItems(data); data.add(Object of your TableView type);`

Comment: @fabian show us all of my program. thanks for help me with my problem. The problem with update the tableview is solved ^^

Comment: @joseclimentpenades is this question completely answered (self answered) or is something remaining? I am not entirely sure.

Comment: @iMan on of 2 questions is solved the question about empty tableview isn't solved. i try to do  `tab.setitems(data)` but it do't result. Thanks for correct my spelling faults.

Comment: If you use the [JavaFX Properties Pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) and fix the values you pass to the `PropertyValueFactory` (i.e. `esport` and `total` instead of `Esport` and `Total`) you should not need the ugly hack of removing a column and adding it back.

Comment: It's not really clear what is still not working. It would be really helpful if you would post a [MCVE] - this means simplifying your example code so that it has enough to reproduce the problem ("complete") but contains no more code than is needed ("minimal"). I am certain that you don't need a model class with 11 properties to reproduce this, for example: one is probably enough. Similarly there is no reason to have so many controls in the example code. OTOH, no-one can actually run this as you don't have any FXML, so the code is not particularly useful for anyone who might want to help you.

Comment: Having said all that, it is extremely suspicious that you are creating an instance of one of your controllers "by hand": `GeneralController aux = new GeneralController();`. This controller instance is obviously not connected to any UI elements, so it's completely unclear what it is for and what you expect it to do. Assuming there are still problems, I suspect this might be the cause of them.

Comment: @James_D I think i putt a minimal code, added full app in mega and explain better my error. Thanks for help and sorry for my grammar.

Comment: @joseclimentpenades Is this question answered yet? If not, I might try helping you on this tonight.

Comment: @iMan I can solve the questin. I show my answered for help other people that have a problem like this. Thanks for help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this question you can do this:
In Main class load the correct controller when you open the 2 window:

```
 private void afegir(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/model/Afegir.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    //load the correct controller
    AfegirController controller = loader.getController();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage ventana2= new Stage();
    ventana2.setMinHeight(380);
    ventana2.getIcons().add(new Image("/estil/Boo.png"));
    ventana2.setMinWidth(770);
    ventana2.setTitle("Afegir dades");
    ventana2.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    ventana2.setScene(scene);
    taula.subs = new ObservableList<Subvencio>();
    ventana2.showAndWait();
    //Add the sub to Observable list here and add the observableList to tableview.
    subs.add(controller.getSub());
    tabla.setItems(subs);
}
```

Next in Afegir class do this:

```
 public Subvencio getSub() {
    return sub;
}
```

This is a public method to get acces to the sub that i like add to the list.
and finally remove this line at afegir Class

```
GeneralController aux = new GeneralController();
aux.subs.add(sub);
```

I do this and my tableview show the items correctly.
Thanks for help me.